# Converting jQuery plugin to AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to use Input Mask [jQuery plugin](http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2012/05/06/masks-with-jquery-mask-plugin/) as a directive but getting the following error in Chrome's console errors.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

My code

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.directive('inputMask', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
             element.mask();
        }
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-mask" data-input-mask data-mask="{mask: 00/00/0000}" placeholder="eg: 23/05/2014">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kp3SYS0cbIfVm1gTwtE0?p=preview

Please help me fix this.

Comment: use already created directive instead creating your own http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length error is because the element.mask() method need an attribute with the mask string you want to use. (in this case '00/00/0000').
So you have to change some things, first your directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.directive('inputMask', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          inputMask: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element){
          element.mask(scope.inputMask.mask);
        }
    }
})
```

And then in the html so you can set the mask in the element.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-input-mask="{mask: '00/00/0000'}" placeholder="eg: 23/05/2014">
```

Here is a Plunker working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BbJtsF9mWx4n29CfZajF?p=preview

Comment: This so cool and thanks. I think whenever the plugin require something from a data-attribute, I need to handle in this way. Thank you very much for the answer and simple explanation. Love you...